# How to show preview of an html document within an ember app

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How to show an html document within ember template without affecting the css styles of ember app ?

The html document has a style tag which conflicts with the css of ember application.

Comment: Are iframes an option you could use in your ember.js application?

Comment: no, that would lead to more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Got a workaround using YUI css reset.

href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset-context/cssreset-context-min.css">

```
<div class="yui3-cssreset"></div>
```